# Force file to be compiled as C, using a directive from the file itself

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, pragma

I have some old code files in my C++ project, that need to be compiled as C code - the entire codebase is set to compile as C++.
I am using Visual Studio, but I'd rather avoid setting this per-file from the project properties, and would rather use some kind of `#pragma` directive (if possible).

I have searched around, but found nothing, the closes I could think of is to add an `#ifdef`, that checks for `__cplusplus` and fails if does so.

Basically I am looking for a way to inject the [/Tc, /Tp, /TC, /TP (Specify Source File Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/lt-lt/cpp/build/reference/tc-tp-tc-tp-specify-source-file-type?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2017) commands from the source.

Comment: Rename the files to have names ending in `.c`. And, if necessary, remove the old files from the project and add the new ones.

Comment: Also remove any "#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" to raise the odds of getting a compile error if it was compiled as C++.

Comment: What does this mean? *"the entire codebase is set to compile as C++"* Do you compile `.c` files as C++?

Comment: at one point the compiler for all source files (`.c` and `.cpp`) were switched to compile as C++, but some external stuff still needs to be compiled as C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"By default, CL assumes that files with the .c extension are C source files and files with the .cpp or the .cxx extension are C++ source files."

So rename the files if nessesary and put the new c files to your projekt.

If neded set the compiler options:
[Set compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/lt-lt/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=msvc-170)

Comment: yes, I realized I will have to do this, was hoping I could avoid rename